# Sites for function reference

Tags: c++, c, function, reference

do you use any particular site for function reference or you just google the function?

Answer (score 5):

For C++ Standard Library functions, I look them up in my paper copy of "The C++ Standard Library" by Nicolai Josuttis. Like most good technical books, it is far superior to any on-line resource.

Comment: ... except that it is now ten years old and is primarily concerned with STL. I think the question was more general than just STL.

Comment: It covers the entire C++ Standard Library.

Comment: Although if it's 10 years old, that means it doesn't include the TCs. So there presumably are a few cases where "The C++ standard", or a draft, is more accurate if less friendly. Still, I don't think there's that much difference.

Comment: True, but my recollection (AKA can't be arsed looking them up) is that the TCs introduce few changes to the Standard Library.

Answer (score 2):

G'day,

I pretty much always go to the project's home page or vendor's site first to see what documentation is available first and then try Googling.

**Edit:** Oops, I forgot add that I am almost always using the "K" functionality of vim to bring up the relevant man page if I am looking at the source code itself. Parking your vim cursor on the function name and hitting the captial-K key with open a new buffer with the relevant man page loaded. Just enter :bd when you want to close the man page and your then back in the source code.

Actually, I'm really beginning to see that more and more a relevent SO question and answer turns up high on the list of Google results.

HTH

cheers,

Answer (score 1):

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/

Answer (score 1):

For C, I use http://man.cx/ or http://linux.die.net/man/ or http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007908799/ and mostly my copy of the [Draft C99 reference](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1401.pdf).

*Update April, 2011*

C99 working paper: http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf
Draft C1X Reference: http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1548.pdf
POSIX.1-2008: http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/

Answer (score 1):

Either http://www.cplusplus.com/ or http://www.dinkumware.com/ for the standard library reference.

Comment: In particular, Dinkumware's *Compleat Libraries Reference* starts here http://www.dinkumware.com/manuals/default.aspx, with the *Standard C++ Library* here: http://www.dinkumware.com/manuals/default.aspx#Standard%20C++%20Library.

Answer (score 1):

95% of my basic C/C++ questions are answered via Google (usually through a link to http://www.cplusplus.com).

Google has the advantage that I get to see at a glance an overview of what problems other people might have been running into with whatever I'm looking up. This isn't usually something of value (because I'm just looking for a refresher or basics), but when it is useful it's pure gold.

If I need more authority or detail, I hit the PDF of the standard document. Then of course there's MSDN (local or on the web) if I need Windows details (which is often enough for me anyway).

Finally when I really want or need background or for curiosity's sake, there's a few shelves full of books from the experts (or their online articles - which Google helps me with, of course).

Answer (score 1):

I use [CPP Reference](http://www.cppreference.com/wiki/start) a lot.  It is not complete, but the pages are simple, uncluttered and easy to read.  When in doubt, I check the paper references.

Answer (score 0):

I use [www.cplusplus.com](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference) a lot.

Answer (score 0):

I still visit the [STL pages at SGI](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/) a lot. It's a good thing these pages are still there even though SGI isn't exactly what it used to be.

The same for [Boost](http://www.boost.org): website is easiest.

However, I consume [Qt](http://qt.nokia.com/) documentation mostly via QtCreator as it is a pretty decent tool, even though I use Emacs to edit my sources.

Answer (score 0):

I have SGI's STL doc, Apache's (formerly Rogue Wave) STDCXX doc and Single Unix Spec (= POSIX) v3 locally.  I run FreeBSD, have man pages installed.

other than that, it's google which usually quickly leads to the sites mentioned in the other answers.

Answer (score 0):

For C I just use man localy in the terminal. I find it supperior to online resources both in terms of speed and accuracy.

Answer (score 0):

I have a PDF of the ISO/IEC 14882 C++ standard.  Costs about $30 to download from the ISO web site, and is indispensible for any "real C++ programmer."